# Font Pairing for Stix

Tags: typography, font-recommendation

I'm currently writing my dissertation and most of the text is set in Stix. I'll have to include a good bit of code and the default Courier looks rather ugly (too wide and doesn't fit well).  Can someone either recommend a good code font to go with Stix or give some pointers on how to properly pair a font with it?

Comment: You're assuming everyone knows what Stix looks like.

Comment: There are too many options and the answer is too opinion based for our Q&A format. See the [help center about "Asking"](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) for more details about what good questions to ask would be

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're using to lay the document out but if you plan to set monospace and STIX on the same line I would focus on linespacing metrics - in other words, does swapping a few words to monospace font in the line of the text throw the linespacing out in your paragraphs? That would be the most distracting thing to avoid.

I don't think most any mono font will complement STIX better than any other - they all have quite different letter structures.